# Infimum of elements in coset is the norm of that coset in quotient space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, quotient-spaces

I'm struggling with the following problem:

> Let $Y$ be a closed subspace of a normed space of $(X,\|\cdot\|)$. Show that the norm $\|\cdot\|_0$ defined on $X/Y$ is given by $$\|\hat{x}\|_0 = \inf_{x\in\hat{x}}\|x\|$$ where $\hat{x} \in X/Y$.

I have previously shown that $\|\hat{x}\|_0 = p(x)$ for $x \in \hat{x}$ where $p$ is a seminorm on $X$. Using this, I think that $p(x) \leq \|x\| \, \forall x\in X$. So if I take a minimizing sequence $x_i \rightarrow \tilde{x} \in \hat{x}$ then $p(\tilde{x}) \leq \|\tilde{x}\|$ so that  $\|\hat{x}\|_0 \leq \|\tilde{x}\|$.

1. I'm having a little trouble with the $\geq$ direction though.
2. I haven't actually shown  $p(x) \leq \|x\| \, \forall x\in X$, I'm getting mixed up with this arguement. I'm pretty sure this is true though -- the seminorm takes non-zero vectors to $0$, the norm only takes the zero vector to $0$.

Comment: But what is your definition of $\|\cdot\|_0$? The above definition you give is the definition I've always seen, but you have to prove it: you must then have something else as your starting point

Comment: maybe I'm mis-interpreting the question statement -- this is Kreyszig Section 2.3, Q14

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/8inwfvck7MWu.png

Comment: You have indeed misinterpreted the question. You have to show that the **DEFINITION** $$\|\hat{x}\|_0:=\inf_{x\in\hat{x}}\|x\|$$Is well-defined and is/induces a norm on the linear space $X/Y$

Comment: @FShrike In the previous problem I showed that a seminorm could be used to define a norm on the quotient space.  Now I have two ways of defining a norm on a quotient space. Should I be able to use the result of the seminorm to prove this infimum definition makes sense?

Comment: What was that seminorm?

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/A7IeBGsPVxsT.png

Comment: The properties referred to in the problem: https://pasteboard.co/NqhKIvmbOjbq.png

Comment: So in the problem above, I'm taking the seminorm to be the function taking everything in the closure to $Y$ to zero

Comment: You haven’t understood the question, I don’t think. Ignore semi-norms for now. Your task is to show $\|\cdot\|_0$ defines a norm on the linear space $X/Y$. One possibly way to do that (using your solution to problem $13$) is to show $p:=\|\cdot\|_0$ is a seminorm and that $Y=p^{-1}(0)$. Then you know this descends to a norm on $X/Y$ (problem 13) so you would be done