# Can these two definitions of norms on a quotient space be shown to be equivalent directly?

Tags: functional-analysis, quotient-spaces

I'm working on some problems related to norms of quotients spaces. There appear to be two definitions for the quotient space norm:

> Let $Y$ be a closed subspace of a normed space of $(X,\|\cdot\|)$. Show that the norm $\|\cdot\|_0$ defined on $X/Y$ is given by
> $$\|\hat{x}\|_0 =  \inf_{x\in\hat{x}}\|x\|$$
> where $\hat{x} \in X/Y$.

And the one defined using the [seminorm](https://pasteboard.co/A7IeBGsPVxsT.png) (properties referred to in the problem [here](https://pasteboard.co/NqhKIvmbOjbq.png))

Should I be able to prove that these norms are equivalent so that $p(x) = \inf_{x \in \hat{x}}\|x\|$?

This is related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4619664/infimum-of-elements-in-coset-is-the-norm-of-that-coset-in-quotient-space?noredirect=1#comment9742782_4619664).

Comment: I don't understand. The "infimum in a coset" link doesn't have an infimum in it anywhere. There's only one definition for the quotient norm and it's the one you gave.

Comment: sorry -- it should have said seminorm